# How to get an xml tag attribute's value in a xml variable

Tags: xml, build.xml

```
<junit>    
<test name="MultiClients" haltonfailure="no" todir="${report}/xml" outfile="TEST-Clients" filtertrace="true">
    <formatter type="xml"/> 
</test>
```

I need the value of the attribute *outfile* stored in a variable which I am gonna use in same xml file to create a folder, as below.

```
<property name="Path" value="$OutFile_${CURRENT_TIME}" />`
```

Comment: use XML parser to achieve that dependihg on what technologies you are using

Comment: I am using it with java/junit.